# Python write elements without comma and brackets

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a list of names as elements in an array (read from a csv file), I want to split the names at the spaces and write it into a csv file. But whenever I do it, it writes it always with brackets and commas.

This is my list:

```
Tom Holl
Lion San
Sonst Salomon
```

This is what I want:

```
Tom 
Holl
Lion 
San
Sonst 
Salomon
```

This is what I get

```
[,',J,o,a,n,n,a
L,u,',]
[,',D,u,n,c,a,n
T,r,u,o,n,g,',]
[,',J,u,d,i,t,h
G,a,l,l,e,g,o,s,',]
```

Btw I am reading the list from a file into elements of an array

```
with open('random_first_names.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\n")
    for i in reader:
    isplit = str(i).split(' ')
    with open('edit_random_first_names.txt', 'a', encoding='UTF-8') as f1:
        writer = csv.writer(f1, lineterminator="\n")
        for x in isplit:
            writer.writerow(x)
```

I tried it with `.split(' ')` and wanted to write them separately but got commas and brackets. Any easy solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you post your code. are the brackets and commas inside the csv file or you mean that you see them when you print them in the screen?

Comment: Like this: [,',J,o,a,n,n,a
L,u,',]
[,',D,u,n,c,a,n
T,r,u,o,n,g,',]
[,',J,u,d,i,t,h
G,a,l,l,e,g,o,s,',]

Comment: @Santos That is not a valid list format.

Comment: don't post relevant information as comments. Edit the question instead. you need to post the list you are referring in the code.

Comment: Okay I have posted my code

Comment: Thank you for posting code. Unfortunately it's not runnable due to indentation issues. Also, why are you using a CSV writer for the output?

Comment: I am learning to write into csv and now playing with txt. So I didnt bother changing the csv writer

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing about the data that suggests CSV is an appropriate format.

Given the input and output file layouts shown in the question, all you need is:

```
INPUT = 'random_first_names.txt'
OUTPUT = 'edit_random_first_names.txt'
ENC = 'UTF-8'

with open(INPUT, encoding=ENC) as indata, open(OUTPUT, 'a', encoding=ENC) as outdata:
    for line in indata:
        print(*line.split(), sep='\n', file=outdata)
```